# C# HTTP Basic authentication Issue

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

this is my C# code right now.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.upcloud.com/1.2/account");
    string authInfo = "username:password";
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.Proxy = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string s = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(s);
```

The code looks fine to me but I get this exception `System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed` when trying to get a response (*HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();*).

What I'm trying to do is basically "translate" the python example reported here https://www.upcloud.com/support/getting-started-upcloud-api/ to C# but regardless of the many attempts I made I still have not found a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time out of your request suggests server side error. So you might be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: First, why aren't you using HttpClient? All of this code could be reduced to 2-3 lines. Second, a timeout means there's a network or server problem. You may have used the *wrong* DNS name. Authentication issues return a 401 immediatelly

Comment: you can use HttpClient it will be easier and reduce your code

Comment: Btw with HttpClient you could have written `var s=await httpClient.GetAsStringAsync(url);`. A couple more lines to add the *Accepted* header (contentType is for responses) and authentication

Comment: The `ContentType` header is for responses, not requests. If you want a JSON response set the `Accept` header. The server probably choked on that, although a well written server should have returned a 400 (bad request)

Comment: HttpWebRequest looked way more simple to me at first but I might be wrong. Anyway, I might not have translated the exception properly, but I just changed my visual studio language to english and this is what i get "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"

Comment: Idk whether it might help or not, but I get the same exception with and without the ContentType line

Comment: I've just tried running the python code in the page I mentioned before. I get a HTTP 200 response. I don't get what's the issue with C#

Comment: I ran your exact code from dotnetfiddle and got an (obviously) unauthorized exception. No timeout. https://dotnetfiddle.net/IhEMDv How long does the request take with the python script.

Comment: You could try to set the `Timeout` property on the request manually (although the default should be 100sec) `request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite` (just for testing purposes)

Comment: That gives me hope. It takes 700 ms for the python script to complete the request. I've tried adding a timeout to the request and changing internet connection but none of these attempts worked